# How to remove a single element from a PHP session array?

Tags: php, arrays, session

I am having a `php` session array like

```
('10/01/2017, '13/02/2017', '21/21/2107')
```

Now how to add and element or remove an element from this array in O(1)

Comment: Which element do you want to remove, or what do you want to add?

Comment: You need either `unset()`, `array_shift()` or `array_pop()`, depending on what you want to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to get the value, remove the item, and set the session variable again.

```
$data = $_SESSION['array'];    // Get the value
unset($data[1]);               // Remove an item (hardcoded the second here)
$_SESSION['array'] = $data;    // Set the session value with the new array
```

**Update:**
Or like @Qirel said, you can unset the item directly if you know the number.

```
unset($_SESSION['array'][1]);
```

**Update 2**
If you want to remove the element by its value, you can use [`array_search`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) to find the key of this element. Note that if there are to elements with this value, only the first will be removed.

```
$value_to_delete = '13/02/2017';
if (($key = array_search($value_to_delete, $_SESSION['array'])) !== false)
    unset($_SESSION['array'][$key]);
```

Comment: Why not just `unset($_SESSION['array'][1]);`?

Comment: I mean, yours will work and achieve the same result - but its an extra two lines ;-)

Comment: I do not know the index value.. i jus to want to delete rhe element say '13/02/2017'.. How can i do that..?

Comment: Thank you soo much

Comment: @Jerodev Can you pls help me with https://www.webdeveloper.com/d/385233-how-to-delete-the-item-from-table

Comment: You should post your question to stack overflow and add more information. Don't just add a link to a code snippet on another question.

Answer (score 0):

To delete and element from an array use unset() function:

```
 <?php
  //session array O
  unset(O["array"][1]);
 ?>
```